# Convert date with milliseconds using PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera

Really stuck on this! Assume I have a following data set:

```
A      |   B
------------------
1/2/12 | 13:3.8 
04:4.1 | 12:1.4
15:4.3 | 1/3/13
```

Observations A and B are in general in the format minutes:seconds.milliseconds like A is a click and B is a response. Sometimes time format has a form of month/day/year if any of the events happens to be in the beginning of the new day.

**What I want?** Is to calculate average difference between B and A. I can easily handle m:s.ms as splitting them into two parts for each A and B and then cast as DOUBLE and perform all needed operations but it all fails when m/d/yy are introduced. The easiest way to omit them but it is not a really good practice. Is there is a clear way to handle such exceptions using PIG?

Comment: why not writing some UDF to do that ? it would be easy to do that in JAVA

Comment: I was just wondering if I can do the same with the use of standard Pig libraries or methods to do that rather than writing my own implementation at the moment.

Comment: @madbitloman : Added an answer by using Pig's String and Date function, try and work on this for your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thought worth contemplating ....

**Ref :** http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html for String and Date functions used.

**Input :**

```
1/2/12|13:3.8
04:4.1|12:1.4
15:4.3|1/3/13
```

**Pig Script :**

```
A = LOAD 'input.csv' USING PigStorage('|') AS  (start_time:chararray,end_time:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE (INDEXOF(end_time,'/',0) > 0 AND LAST_INDEX_OF(end_time,'/') > 0 AND (INDEXOF(end_time,'/',0) != LAST_INDEX_OF(end_time,'/')) 
                ? (ToUnixTime(ToDate(end_time,'MM/dd/yy')))  : (ToUnixTime(ToDate(end_time,'mm:ss.S')))) - 
                (INDEXOF(start_time,'/',0) >0  AND LAST_INDEX_OF(start_time,'/') > 0 AND (INDEXOF(start_time,'/',0) != LAST_INDEX_OF(start_time,'/')) 
                ? (ToUnixTime(ToDate(start_time,'MM/dd/yy')))  : (ToUnixTime(ToDate(start_time,'mm:ss.S')))) AS diff_time;
C = FOREACH (GROUP B ALL) GENERATE AVG(B.diff_time);
DUMP C;
```

**N.B.** In place of ToUnixTime we can use ToMilliSeconds() method.

**Output :**

```
(1.0569718666666666E7)
```

Comment: Wow, will try this one!